# VS2015 with VC++ 2008 toolset template deduction failure

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2008, visual-c++-2015

Sample code to reproduce the problem:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template< typename T, typename Func >
void action(Func T::* func)
{
    T entry;
    (entry.*func)();
}

struct A
{
    void f()
    {
        std::cout << "A::f()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    action(&A::f);
    return 0;
}
```

This code successfully compiles using MS VC++2008, with VC++2015 using vc140 toolset, but fails to compile when used in VC++2015 project with vc90 (VC++2008) toolset. Gives strange diagnostics of

```
cpptest.cpp(20): error C2664: 'action' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void (__thiscall A::* )(void)' to 'void (A::* )(void)'
      Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

Seems compiler looses __thiscall calling convention specifier when deducing type for Func. Tried to forcibly specify __thiscall in different parts of the code but had no success. Converting the whole project to vc14 toolset is not a way because of various dependencies and keeping it under the VS 2008 is an unlikely way. Any ideas to force compiler to understand such a construction?

## Update

Changing code to

```
template< typename T, typename Func >
void action(Func func)
....
```

and calling to `action< A >( &A::f );` works, but looks little ugly - I expect compiler to be able to deduce type for both template arguments (T and Func) automatically

Comment: Really it's an ugly solution. But the whole problem looks like a VC++ bug.